# Web.config nested lists

Tags: c#-4.0

I would like to use nested list in my web.config. I see pieces of code that work, but not mine, i have an error when i try to read the configuration section :

> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException : Élément non
>   reconnu IsochroneServicesTestImbrique'.

My config :

```
<IsochroneServicesTest>
    <add name="TC">
      <IsochroneServicesTestImbrique>
        <add name="DEFAULT" path="success"/>
      </IsochroneServicesTestImbrique>
    </add>
  </IsochroneServicesTest>
```

and the code :

```
    [ConfigurationProperty("IsochroneServicesTest")]
    [ConfigurationCollection(typeof(CollectionIsochrone), AddItemName = "add")]
    public CollectionIsochroneType IsochroneServicesTest
    {
        get { return (CollectionIsochroneType)this["IsochroneServicesTest"]; }
        set { this["IsochroneServicesTest"] = value; }
    }

    public class CollectionIsochroneType : ConfigurationElementCollection
    {
        public void Add(ProviderElement element)
        {
            base.BaseAdd(element);
        }

        protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
        {
            return new IsochroneElement();
        }

        protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
        {
            return ((IsochroneTypeElement)element).Name;
        }

        public IsochroneTypeElement this[int index]
        {
            get { return (IsochroneTypeElement)BaseGet(index); }
            set
            {
                if (BaseGet(index) != null)
                {
                    BaseRemoveAt(index);
                }
                BaseAdd(index, value);
            }
        }

        public new IsochroneTypeElement this[string Name]
        {
            get { return (IsochroneTypeElement)BaseGet(Name); }
        }

        public int IndexOf(IsochroneTypeElement element)
        {
            return BaseIndexOf(element);
        }

        protected override void BaseAdd(ConfigurationElement element)
        {
            BaseAdd(element, false);
        }
    }

    public class IsochroneTypeElement : ConfigurationElement
    {
        [ConfigurationProperty("name", IsRequired = true)]
        public string Name
        {
            get { return (string)this["name"]; }
            set { this["name"] = value; }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("IsochroneServicesTestImbrique", IsRequired = true)]
        [ConfigurationCollection(typeof(CollectionIsochrone), AddItemName = "add")]
        public CollectionIsochrone IsochroneServicesImbrique
        {
            get { return (CollectionIsochrone)this["IsochroneServicesTestImbrique"]; }
            set { this["IsochroneServicesTestImbrique"] = value; }
        }
    }

public class CollectionIsochrone : ConfigurationElementCollection
{
    public void Add(ProviderElement element)
    {
        base.BaseAdd(element);
    }

    protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
    {
        return new IsochroneElement();
    }

    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
    {
        return ((IsochroneElement)element).Name;
    }

    public IsochroneElement this[int index]
    {
        get { return (IsochroneElement)BaseGet(index); }
        set
        {
            if (BaseGet(index) != null)
            {
                BaseRemoveAt(index);
            }
            BaseAdd(index, value);
        }
    }

    public new IsochroneElement this[string Name]
    {
        get { return (IsochroneElement)BaseGet(Name); }
    }

    public int IndexOf(IsochroneElement element)
    {
        return BaseIndexOf(element);
    }

    protected override void BaseAdd(ConfigurationElement element)
    {
        BaseAdd(element, false);
    }
}

public class IsochroneElement : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("name", IsRequired = true)]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return (string)this["name"]; }
        set { this["name"] = value; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("path", IsRequired = true)]
    public string Path
    {
        get { return (string)this["path"]; }
        set { this["path"] = value; }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting that error because you are missing the declaration for `IsochroneServicesTestImbrique` in your `<configSections>` section. Also, at least one class must inherit from `ConfigurationSection`. See the example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).